# POST request on fetch is returning a 400 (read question)

Tags: javascript, flask, fetch, bad-request

I have a question.

I am using the `fetch` API for JS, and am trying to send a POST request to a server. However, the server responds with a 400, or "bad request". The server in question is a flask webserver.

The code:

```
fetch('https://webserver.com/post', {
        method: "POST", 
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(alert('Post created!'))
```

where `data` is a global variable containing my data that I want to send in the request.

The server code (in Python):

```
@app.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
def newpost():
    data1 = request.form['data1']
    data2 = request.form['data2']
    data3 = request.form['data3']
    if data1 in list(db.keys()):
        resp = Response('error')
    else:
        db[data1] = [data2, data3]
        resp = Response('Success')
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    print('yep we got a post request')
    return resp
```

and here, `db` is my database.

What should be happening is the server send back a 200, and saves the data in the database. Does anyone know why I am getting the 400, and how to fix it?

Comment: _"Ask for more code or extra details in comments please."_ That's not how Stackoverflow works. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask can be picky about Content types, so it's better to specify the `Content-Type` header. Also, `request.form` works for **HTML** forms but you are sending a **JSON**, so you are looking to something like:

```
fetch('https://webserver.com/post', {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    cache: "no-cache",
    headers: new Headers({
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    })
  })
  .then(alert('Post created!'))
```

On the JS side of the things.

And for your Flask app:

```
@app.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
def newpost():
    data0 = request.get_json()
    data1 = data0['data1']
    data2 = data0['data2']
    data3 = data0['data3']
    if data1 in list(db.keys()):
        resp = Response('error')
    else:
        db[data1] = [data2, data3]
        resp = Response('Success')
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    print('yep we got a post request')
    return resp
```

This assumes that the JSON `data` that you are sending contains the properties `data1`, `data2` and `data3`